# Can i install two seperate applications on the same Sql Server 2008 port

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed SharePoint 2013 on port 1433 for my SQL Server2008 r2. and now I want to install another application on the same server. and for the second application I need to use MS SQL server . so inside the installation wizard I define the server name , login user name and password. and when I specified the port number for my sql server 2008 r2 which is 1433; the following message appears "the same port number is already occupied by another application , do you want to proceed?"

so it is right to install two applications on the same sql server port? or I need o define a new port number?

Comment: When you say you are installing apps on port 1433, do you mean they are using 1433 to talk to SQL or did you select that port for the app to communicate with its clients?

Comment: 1433 port to talk to SQL

Comment: i defined a new port number. by going to ---> configuration manager ---> tcp/ip---->IPALL --> TCP Port. now i have two ports 1433,4444. but on the installation wizard if i define port 4444, i will get the same message "the same port number is already occupied by another application , do you want to proceed?". so if i chose to continue with port 4444,  will SharePoint which is using the 1433 port be affected ? and why it is mentioning that the 4444 port is used by another application although i have just added it ?